# Does the derivative of the restriction equal the restriction of the derivative?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, submanifold

Consider a function $f$ defined over a $n$-dimensional manifold $\mathcal{M}$ and assume $f$ is the restriction of a function $g$ defined over a vector space of dimension $n+1$.

*Example*: $$f:\mathcal{S}^2\ni u\mapsto \dfrac{u}{\|u\|}\quad \text{and}\quad g:\mathbb{R}^3\ni v\mapsto \dfrac{v}{\|v\|}.$$

*Question*: Under what conditions do the covariant derivatives of $f$ and $g$ coincide on $\mathcal{M}$? In other words, is the derivative of the restriction equal to the restriction of the derivative?

Comment: Why do you say covariant derivative when we're talking about functions?

Comment: @TedShifrin Is that correct: covariant derivative are defined for vector fields, and here $f$ is not a vector field, because its image is not in $T\mathcal{M}$?

Comment: The point is that the *covariant derivative* of a vector field is defined, as you said, only for vector fields tangent to the (sub)manifold. In your case, the vector field is far from tangential, as it's normal. But the "restricted" covariant derivative—for a vector field tangent to the submanifold—is computed by taking the covariant derivative in the ambient space and then *projecting* to the tangent space of the submanifold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes: to see this, use the chain rule and the usual identification $T_pM\simeq di_p(T_pM)\subset\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, where $i:M\to \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is the inclusion. Namely, you have by definition that $f|_M=f\circ i$, and

$$d(f|_M)_p=d(f\circ i)_p=df_{i(p)}\circ di_p=df_p\circ di_p$$

leads to $d(f|_M)_p=df_p|_{T_pM}$.